# Flutter: Your Android App Bundle is signed with the wrong key

Tags: flutter, google-play-console, signing

I'm new to Flutter. I have created an app and now I'm trying to upload it to google play (Open testing track). Previously, I have uploaded a react-native version of my app. Now I would like to replace it with the flutter version. I have carefully followed the instructions from the [official guidelines](https://flutter.dev/docs/deployment/android). No matter what I do, I'm getting the error:

```
Your Android App Bundle is signed with the wrong key. Ensure that your App Bundle is signed with the correct signing key and try again
```

I have looked at a number of similar issues on Stackoverflow. I have looked again and again at my `app/build.gradle` to make sure release mode is selected. I have cleaned every thing with `flutter clean` then re-generated the bundel (.app) with no success. Here is a portion of my `app/build.gradle` file:

```
signingConfigs {
       release {
           keyAlias keystoreProperties['keyAlias']
           keyPassword keystoreProperties['keyPassword']
           storeFile keystoreProperties['storeFile'] ? file(keystoreProperties['storeFile']) : null
           storePassword keystoreProperties['storePassword']
       }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }
    }
```

I am at lost here, any help would be greatly appreciated. I don't know if the issue is related to the previous react-native artifact I have previously uploaded (which by the way, I can't delete from Google Play Console bundles explorer)

Comment: Well, the error message is rather clear. You need to sign your new app with the same key that you've used to sign the React Native version.

Comment: Thanks for the replay. How do I proceed? Do I find that react-native key? (It was not generated locally, I used the react-native-expo cloud service to generate that early version...)

Comment: I'd simply [build the release `.apk`](https://flutter.dev/docs/deployment/android#build-an-app-bundle) and then manually upload the unsigned `.apk` as explained in [Manually uploading your app for the first time](https://docs.expo.io/distribution/uploading-apps/#manually-uploading-your-app-for-the-first). Having said that, I have never tried doing so.

Comment: The new version is written with Flutter, not react-native. Also I'm trying to upload the aap, not apk

Comment: I am migrating from RN to flutter, facing the same issue, please help !.

Answer (score 1):

You can download the correct Upload Key Certificate from the Google Play console. To validate you are downloading the correct key, check the error output which displays the key ID and make sure it matches.

With this key, you follow the instructions here (https://docs.flutter.dev/deployment/android#create-an-upload-keystore) to create an Upload Keystore and then reference this Key using those instructions for adding signing to Gradle.